# How to re-use the same generic page in several specific pages in ASP.Net Core Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am a beginner in `html` and `razor` design and coding. I am trying to implement a simple `cshtml`-based page that handles the display and the management of some data stored in a `csv` file. The page provides a form to carry out the 'insert' action and displays the `csv` file on a table. Each row of the table is combined with a 'delete' button to remove the designated line.

I would like to re-use this generic page model and data (id-name) model into different specialised pages: each page would have its own name and would be based on a different data file (or a different table if the underlying data were stored on a DB).

Here is my code based on a simplified data model (id-name).

First, the (simple) model in the Data.cs file:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class Data
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then, the Data.cshmtl.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using WebApp.Models;

namespace WebApp.Pages
{
    [BindProperties]
    public class DataModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
        private readonly char[] _delim = { ',' };
        private string DataFile => Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, FileName);
        public List<Data> DataList { get; set; } = new List<Data>();
        public Data DataItem { get; set; } = new Data();
        public string TitleName { get; set; } = "Data Set";
        public string FileName { get; set; } = "FileName.csv";
        public string[] Headers = new string[]
        {
            "Id",
            "Name",
        };

        private void LoadFile()
        {
            <!-- Loading DataFile to DataList -->
        }

        public void InsertIntoFile(Data dataNew)
        {
            <!-- Inserting dataNew into DataList and DataFile -->
        }

        public void DeleteFromFile(Data dataOld)
        {
            <!-- Deleting dataOld from DataFile -->
        }

        public DataModel(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            LoadFile();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostInsert()
        {
            InsertIntoFile(DataItem);
            LoadFile();
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostDelete()
        {
            DeleteFromFile(DataItem);
            LoadFile();
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the Data.cshtml file:

```
@page
@using WebApp.Models;
@model WebApp.Pages.DataModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = @Model.TitleName;
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Insert">
    <div>
        <label>
            <text>Data id:&nbsp;</text>
            <input asp-for="DataItem.Id" required placeholder="Enter the data id">
            <text>Data name:&nbsp;</text>
            <input asp-for="DataItem.Name" required placeholder="Enter the data name">
        </label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Insert
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
<br />
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:400px;">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (string header in Model.Headers)
                {
                    <th>@header</th>
                }
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (Data dataItem in Model.DataList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@dataItem.Id</td>
                    <td>@dataItem.Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Delete">
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@dataItem.Id" required>
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@dataItem.Name" required>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I do not really know how to proceed from there in order to re-use this framework to manage data from/to any other file on a corresponding page: I would like to factorise this code (I would like to use the same insert/delete/table skeleton on different pages without having to re-write the same thing) with the simple difference that I would need to target different underlying `csv` files for each different page.

What I have done so far but it does not work is to modify the constructor of the above     Data.cshtml.cs file to

```
public DataModel(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, string titleName, string fileName)
{
    _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    TitleName = titleName;
    FileName = fileName;
}
```

and to create another `razor` view, with the Data1.cshtml.cs file looking like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApp.Pages
{
    [BindProperties]
    public class Data1Model : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
        public string TitleName = "Data Set 1";
        public string FileName = "File1Name.csv";

        public Data1Model(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            DataModel data = new DataModel(_webHostEnvironment, TitleName, FileName);
            data.OnGet();
        }
    }
}
```

and the Data1.cshtml file (with some argument redundancies) looking like:

```
@page
@using WebApp.Models;
@model WebApp.Pages.Data1Model
@{
    Layout = "Data";
}

<a asp-page="Data"
   asp-route-titleName="Data Set 1"
   asp-route-fileName="File1Name.csv"></a>
```

It does not work on the OnGet() of Data1.cshtml.cs (it goes through the code but does not render any result) and I don't know how to implement the actions OnPostInsert() and OnPostDelete().

Comment: Havr you looked into `partial` pages? `<partial name="...." />` Yo can pass a `Model` to render each partial differently.